# Regex Text followed by number only

Tags: regex

Is there a way of regex to filter this list that after `/` only have number

```
abc/12345
abc/123def
abc/fgh99d
abc/19234f
abc/910190
abc/abc123
```

become:

```
abc/12345
abc/910190
```

Comment: To match a digit just use `\d` or `[0-9]`

Comment: I've tried something like `/abc\/\d+/`, but this won't filter out for case 'abc/123def' and 'abc/19234f'

Comment: You need a `$`, too, `/\d+$`

Comment: sorry, I forgot another case, like 'abc/abc123', this should be excluded too.

Comment: nvm, I think this  `/abc\/\d{1,}$/` should have solve my problem. Thanks for the hint